# Can't connect to local Coherence Cluster

Tags: c#, oracle-coherence

I have a `Coherence cluster` running on my local machine, and a C# application that is trying to connect to it. I am getting the error:

> Could not establish a connection to one of the following addresses:
>   XXXX. Make sure the remote addresses element contains the IP address
>   and port of a running TcpAcceptor.

Here is the remote addresses section of my client config:

```
<socket-address>
    <address>localhost</address>
    <port>9099</port>
</socket-address>
```

I can't connect to this address or any of our other environments, which are working for other existing code. I confirmed that the cluster was running using a Coherence Console node. What are some possible causes other than the obvious incorrect IP address? What else can go wrong?

Is it possible to confirm that a `"running TcpAcceptor"` is on my machine?

Before I added the config file, it threw an exception saying that it was missing cache-config.xml. All our other code uses coherence-cache-config.xml instead; is this important?

Answer (score 1):

Issue resolved. The problem: although I had coherence.xml and cache-config.xml in the project and they were being used, I was missing the POF config. I added a coherence section to my app.config explicitly referencing these files and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

check if local-config.xml in your proxy node defined properly.

```
   <tcp-acceptor>
      <local-address>
        <address>localhost</address>            
        <port>9099</port>
      </local-address>
      <suspect-buffer-size>1000000000</suspect-buffer-size>
    </tcp-acceptor>
```